# What AWS Configuration Should We Use In Production?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have been researching AWS. It seems a little confusing to me. We want a single box for production purposes before we go live. It will have MySQL, SVN, Java, and a few other custom attributes.

1) What features of AWS should I sign up for if we are only developing - not live. Can you suggest a configuration? We are looking to keep our costs as low as possible right now.

2) Is it possible to get an instance with pre-bundled stuff like SVN and MySQL? Where do i Look?

3) What instance type should I be selecting if we are only developing? Here are my choices:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

4) Which would be more cost-effective for us - reserved or on-demand? I suppose on-demand would be cheap because we have no traffic other than dev stuff but I like that the reserved instances will let me know what I will be spending ahead of time. Anybody have any experience here?

Thanks.

Comment: If you didn't know already, there is a [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) for new AWS customers.

Comment: I tried that but it tells me that I have already signed up for AWS - which I did (recently). I am still a new customer and would really like to take advantage of this but getting in touch of anybody at Amazon to talk about this borders on impossible... any ideas>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You probably want to start with EC2.  After that you can have a look at for example S3.

2) Yes, in the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) for EC2 search for ready-built AMIs (Amazon Machine Image) that contain what you need pre-configured.

3) You can start with Micro instances which are the cheapest.  Note though that they are 32-bit only.  When you feel Micro instances are too limiting (need more memory or CPU power), just switch up to the Small instance type.

4) The only way to know if Reserved instances are cheaper than On-Demand for your use case is to estimate the number of hours of each instance type you expect to consume during the next 1 or 3 years, and compare the cost in dollars of the two options.  If your development instances are left running over night (i.e., they are running around the clock), then most certainly Reserved instances will be cheaper if you are sure you will keep using AWS for at least 1 or 3 years.

Comment: thanks Seppo. Yes, I was thinking Micro was right. Thanks for that. I have also added one more question if you have some time... thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again. It sounds Like an EC2 ready-built AMI reserved micro instance is the way to go for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: For future readers: Micro instances are now available in 64-bit as well, which means no more need to use 32-bit anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a few things to [@Seppo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171337/what-aws-configuration-should-we-use-in-production/5171470#5171470) answer.

- I would not start with a reserved
  instance. What if you reserve an
  instance and then it turns out to be
  not suitable. Test it first (even if
  its only for a few hours) on the
  normal pay as you go tariff. You can
  easily change the existing instance
  to a reserved instance later. Just
  by purchasing a reserved instance,
  you will change your billing rate on
  the existing instance.
- You do not have to run a reserved instance for the full year (or 3) to save money. You are not paying for the entire period up front - only a deposit - so you only need to run it for a few months (depending on the instance type) to break even.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. I have followed Seppo's advice and have already purchased a micro instance for a year. Maybe this wasn't the way to go but I am new to this and amazon won't give me the free tier option. This does, however, raise some issues for me. Namely, how do i gain SSH access to this reserved instance? And, how do I customize it? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Stop thinking about it as some foreign thing, and think about your instance as a physical server. It's running whatever Linux distribution the AMI you chose was built from. You SSH the same as a server sitting next to you (with a key pair or username/login, depending on how you set up the security group you started it under). You install MySQL, SVN or Java the same as you would on a server sitting next to you (compile the source or use the distribution's package manager), etc. IMO, reserving a micro instance for a year is a very foolish thing...